# get the following error on selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I get the following error on selenium,
I don't know how to fix it or what I should do,

> unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
>     (Session info: chrome=29.0.1547.57)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 3 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_04'
>   Session ID: 6c0f76e6f67873a6318edab1d66e4ccf
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.2}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=29.0.1547.57, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
>   Command duration or timeout: 2.27 seconds

please help

Comment: What were you doing when it happened?

Comment: trying to initialize webdriver with a Url

Comment: What is the URL? Notice the error text `Cannot navigate to invalid URL`

Comment: the URL is fine, it happens only since i updated to the latest version of the chromedriver,
with older version i can open the URL and get no errors

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Selenium?

Comment: yes i'm using the latest version of selenium and chromedriver

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium error - Cannot navigate to invalid URL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18429680/1699210)

Answer (score 1):

I too got this error "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: **unhandled inspector error**: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}"

To remove hardcoded URL and calling a URL from a file 
I defined like this - ex: url="https://test.com" then I got the above error, after so many research and failures - simply **I removed double quotes**...it worked
ex: url=https://test.com

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you´re using relative path to open the link. You can use absolute path (starting with `http://`) or - if it is an internal link/button on the web - you can mapp it as `WebElement` and perform `click()` method.

Answer (score -3):

We managed to overcome the above error by changing the initialization Url. but now we are experiencing a bunch of new issues the latest chrome version, latest chromedriver and latest selenium versions.
Everything is extremely slow and we get many timeout since than.

Comment: This is not a helpful post. Please elaborate as to what specifically you changed to get it to work. Also complaints about a 1year old version of chrome driver are obsolete and not helpful to new readers of this post